# How to make batch script from bash

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file, cmd

Can someone help me write this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter filename extension and press [Enter]: "
read ext
cd /mnt/d/cba
for i in *.$ext ; do
cutext=`echo $i | rev | cut -d"." -f2- | rev`
mv $i $cutext-$(date +%Y%m%d).$ext
done
echo Done
```

To a windows batch file? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Which command do you have problems with? If there is more than one, make a separate question for each single problem.

Comment: I just don't know the syntax of batch. Mostly this is difficult to me:
"cutext=`echo $i | rev | cut -d"." -f2- | rev`"

Comment: Then I suggest to open a new question, titled maybe "how do I catch the stdout of a pipe into a variable using batch", because I think this would be of interest to many people.

Comment: Some of those commands are not even available in Windows.  You could make this easy on yourself and install the Windows Subsystem for Linux onto your Windows computer and just use your Bash script using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF

SET /p ext="Enter filename extension and press [Enter]: "

CD SOME\PATH\HERE

SET YYYYMMDD=%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%

FOR %%i in (*.%ext%) do (
MOVE %%i %%~ni-%YYYYMMDD%.%ext%
)

ECHO Done
```

Comment: Alex, what happens if the name of a file was `help.me.ext`? My interpretation is that `rev` would change it to `txe.em.pleh`, then `cut -d"." -f2` would select `em`, then `rev` would change it back to `me`. The intention may be to have `me-20200302.ext` as the new name, not `help.me-20200302.ext`. Additionally, there are much better ways of setting a date string to a variable, than four `for /f` loops, especially when they're not locale independent. Finally there's already a special variable named `date`, do not overwrite it, choose another name.

Comment: `cut` parameter is `-f2-`, not `-f2`, so that command just cuts away everything after the last dot, the remaining of the string stays. Other suggestions are valid

Comment: Sorry Alex, I didn't notice, the additional `-`. However, your answer, whilst accepted, is currently incorrect, for my date format and many other people's, and should certainly be modified based upon my valid suggestions.

Comment: The answer is modified

Comment: That's fine for you perhaps Alex, but it still assumes that your `%date%` and other people's, return the same number of characters, and in the same order, which is not the case.

Comment: Can you, please, provide the locale-independent answer?

Comment: Sorry Alex, the question cannot receive further answers as it has been closed. I would therefore advise that you seek the methodology using the site search facility.